# Can objective c calls be optimized using stack variables?

Tags: objective-c, optimization, memory-management, stack

Am I missing something, or to call sendData do I really need to create 3 NS objects on the heap like this?  Or is this even created on the heap?  Is there anyway to create them on the stack instead?  This seems inefficient!

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:packet->data length:packet->dataLength];
if(!data)
    return -5;
NSString *player = [NSString initWithCString:(char*)peer->data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if(!player)
    return -6;
NSArray *to = [NSArray arrayWithObject:player];
if(!to)
    return -7;

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [[GCHelper sharedInstance].match sendData:data toPlayers:to withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];
if (!success) {
    printf("Error sending packet %08x %d\n", packet->data, packet->dataLength);
    return -8;
}
```

Can I do something like this instead?

```
NSData data;
[data dataWithBytes:packet->data length:packet->dataLength];
NSString player;
[player initWithCString:(char*)peer->data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSArray to;
[to arrayWithObject:player];
```

Sorry for my ignorance, I am well versed with C++ but am new to Objective-C.

Comment: As CodaFi points out you're yearning after C++'s stack allocated objects (which have advantages in some cases, but are also fundamentally broken in some other cases unless the Standard has been fixed - you can, or could, end up with objects with the wrong vtables, but I digress). If this is not premature optimisation you can address the issue by declaring a method on whatever class `GCHelper.sharedInstance.match` is that takes your `char *` etc. directly and constructs the packet from those without wrapping and unwrapping them as heap objects. HTH.

Comment: sendData is a GameKit API call, isn't it impossible to declare another function as you suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately if you are calling into a framework you need another solution. Too long to write here, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative for you *if* performance is an issue. As you rightly point out in response to my comment on the question you cannot unfortunately add your own method which takes your data as C pointers as you are calling into a framework. However you can do a similar thing one level up, you can create the `NSData` and `NSString` *without copying your data* itself to the heap:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:packet->data
                                    length:packet->dataLength
                              freeWhenDone:NO];
if(!data)
   return -5;

NSString *player = [NSString initWithBytesNoCopy:peer->data
                                          length:strlen(peer->data)
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                    freeWhenDone:NO];
if(!player)
   return -6;

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [[GCHelper sharedInstance].match sendData:data
                                               toPlayers:@[player] // array expression
                                            withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable
                                                   error:&error];
if (!success)
{
   printf("Error sending packet %08x %d\n", packet->data, packet->dataLength);
   return -8;
}
```

This still wraps your data as  heap objects but doesn't both the `NSData` and `NSString` heap objects directly reference your data. You must make sure your data stays alive as long as in needed of course!

Note: If you are getting into Objective-C and will need this functionality often then you can wrap the above code up as a *category* on `GKMatch` - that is left as an exercise :-)

Comment: Now this looks like its getting somewhere, thank you!  Some questions though: 1) don't you think sendData copies the supplied data anyways, since it has to buffer the data and send it, and if so wouldn't it simply addref the supplied allocated NSData object and keep it around?  2) doesn't the array expression still allocate an NSArray object and put it on the heap, its just a more concise way to do it?

Comment: The only benefit this provides is that your data doesn't get copied off to the heap.  You still cannot allocate objects on the stack.

Comment: @CodaFi - Exactly, but its the measure of "only" that matters here - *if* performance is an issue removing a redundant buffer copy might be important.

Comment: @Rasterman (1) If the data is not used by `sendData` before it returns then you don't want to use `...NoCopy` *or* stack allocated objects (as in C++) or you are in trouble! In that case you might want to look at using `...NoCopy` with `freeWhenDone:YES` - that expects a `malloc`'ed block which it will release (you don't give the origin of your structure, so I cannot say if this will suit). (2) the array expression still allocates a heap object, its just more concise. Note that allocation is Obj-C is generally cheap, but of course YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do something like this instead?

No.  Besides the fact that `-init` and friends do *no actual initialization* (take a look at NSObject.mm, all it does is `return self;`), you're just messaging nil with those calls.  `+alloc` exists solely to provide an implementation-independent allocator function; one that happens to allocate objects on the heap.  If you are worried about the performance of Objective-C itself, then you don't have to use it.  You can drop back to C and C++ at any time and return to the land of stack-allocated variables and complex pointer arithmetic that you know and love.  Objective-C is still a performant language, despite it's "inefficiencies."

Remember though: while C and C++ were designed for embedded systems and mission critical applications where memory and processor efficiency are king, Objective-C is designed to run on fairly consistent, performant, and (relatively) memory-unconstrained hardware.

Comment: So I can create a C++ NSData, NSString, and NSArray and pass those to sendData?  Do you know what the C++ variants of those are called?

Comment: There are no C++ variants, and even if you made them it would be a pain to bridge them over to Objective-C objects.

Comment: Thank you.  So to make this sendData call there must be 6 memory allocations and the checks for those failing?  3 for the objects, 1 for the data, 1 for the player string, and 1 for the element in the NSArray.  Sorry but if that isn't inefficient I don't know what is lol.  Not to mention the only allocation actually doing anything is the data one, the others are simply API bridging balarky.  BTW yes this is premature optimization, perhaps it will make no difference, (on a 3gs mobile cpu?) but since I am learning Objective-C I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: @Rasterman The problem is that you're calling the design of the language itself inefficient (and it definitely is compared to others, I'm not arguing that), and there's no way to remedy that but to write a better language or get low-level.

Comment: I did not know that until you educated me though, so thank you.  A related question are the allocation checks for if(!data) if(!player) etc necessary?  Those objects are dynamically allocated and can fail to be allocated correct?

Comment: @Rasterman They could fail, though that is exceptionally unlikely.  The allocations are unlikely to be a performance bottleneck unless you are going through that codepath very rapidly repeatedly.  Note also that `initWithCString:` is deprecated.  Use `initWithUTF8String:` instead.   Note also that you missed a +alloc on that C string creation method.